# Creating new table from data of other tables

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL and I hope someone can help me with some SQL syntax.  I have a database with these tables and fields,

- `DATA`: data_id, person_id, attribute_id, date, value
- `PERSONS`: person_id, parent_id, name
- `ATTRIBUTES`: attribute_id, attribute_type

attribute_type can be "Height" or "Weight"

### Question 1

Give a person's "Name", I would like to return a table of "Weight" measurements for each children.  Ie: if John has 3 children names Alice, Bob and Carol, then I want a table like this

```
| date | Alice | Bob | Carol |
```

I know how to get a long list of children's weights like this:

```
select d.date, 
       d.value 
  from data d, 
       persons child, 
       persons parent, 
       attributes a 
 where parent.name='John' 
   and child.parent_id = parent.person_id 
   and d.attribute_id = a.attribute_id 
   and a.attribute_type = "Weight';
```

but I don't know how to create a new table that looks like:

```
| date | Child 1 name | Child 2 name | ... | Child N name |
```

### Question 2

Also, I would like to select the attributes to be between a certain range.

### Question 3

What happens if the dates are not consistent across the children?  For example, suppose Alice is 3 years older than Bob, then there's no data for Bob during the first 3 years of Alice's life.  How does the database handle this if we request all the data?

Answer (score 2):

1) It might not be so easy.  MS SQL Server can `PIVOT` a table on an axis, but dumping the resultset to an array and sorting there (assuming this is tied to some sort of program) might be the simpler way right now if you're new to SQL.

If you can manage to do it in SQL it still won't be enough info to create a new table, just return the data you'd use to fill it in, so some sort of external manipulation will probably be required.  But you can probably just use `INSERT INTO [new table] SELECT [...]` to fill that new table from your select query, at least.

2) You can join on `attributes` for each unique attribute:

```
SELECT [...] FROM data AS d
JOIN persons AS p ON d.person_id = p.person_id
JOIN attributes AS weight ON p.attribute_id = weight.attribute_id
HAVING weight.attribute_type = 'Weight'
JOIN attributes AS height ON p.attribute_id = height.attribute_id
HAVING height.attribute_type = 'Height'
[...]
```

(The way you're joining in the original query is just shorthand for `[INNER] JOIN .. ON`, same thing except you'll need the `HAVING` clause in there)

3) It depends on the type of `JOIN` you use to match parent/child relationships, and any dates you're filtering on in the `WHERE`, if I'm reading that right (entirely possible I'm not).  I'm not sure quite what you're looking for, or what kind of database you're using, so no good answer. If you're new enough to SQL that you don't know the different kinds of `JOIN`s and what they can do, it's very worthwhile to [learn them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) - they put the R in RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will read about the various types of JOINs.

I'm actually working with mySQL and Python.  Some of these tables also have corresponding django objects in Python.  Does that make things easier?

Comment: Lots easier, I'd think.  Might want to update the question or start a new one though - it's more of a Python / object-manipulation problem than just SQL now, unless someone knows a way to fake a pivot in MySQL.  Lots of Pythoneers around here who'd have better answers than I would.

Answer (score 0):

when you do a select, you need to specify the exact columns you want. In other words you can't return the Nth child's name. Ie this isn't possible:

```
1/2/2010 | Child_1_name | Child_2_name | Child_3_name
1/3/2010 | Child_1_name 
1/4/2010 | Child_1_name | Child_2_name
```

Each record needs to have the same amount of columns. So you might be able to make a select that does this:

```
1/2/2010 | Child_1_name
1/2/2010 | Child_2_name
1/2/2010 | Child_3_name
1/3/2010 | Child_1_name 
1/4/2010 | Child_1_name
1/4/2010 | Child_2_name
```

And then in a report remap it to how you want it displayed

Comment: You need to fix your formatting. Try putting four spaces before each line in your tables.

Comment: So there's no default way to make the number of columns to be the maximum possible and fill in NULL's for the absent values?

Comment: sure... you could do that. But without getting really deep into it, you'd need to do something like this
SELECT p.date, c1.name, c2.name, c3.name
FROM persons p, persons c1, persons c2, persons c3
WHERE c1.child_index=1 AND c2.child_index=2 AND c3.child_index=3
  AND c1.parent_id = p.person_id.... etc etc..

You probably also need to do outer joins, and not an inner join as i show above... but you get the point